# RequireJS with jQuery Validation - Set the Default Settings

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, requirejs, unobtrusive-validation

I've already managed to get the jQuery validation plugin to work with RequireJs. I'm now trying to set the jquery validation default parameters so that it doesn't validate fields wrapped in a tag with an attribute of data-prefix (this is done in the Page1.js file). However when you click the submit button it tries to validate both fields.

Here's the code (the original question linked to a more complex demo):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.5/require.js"></script>
    <script>
        require.config({
            paths: {
                'jquery': 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.3',
                'jquery.validate': 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate',
                'jquery.validate.unobtrusive': 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive'
            },
            shim: {
                'jquery.validate': ['jquery'],
                'jquery.validate.unobtrusive': ['jquery', 'jquery.validate']
            }
        });

        require(['jquery', 'jquery.validate', 'jquery.validate.unobtrusive'], function($) {
            $.validator.setDefaults({
                ignore: '[data-js-val-prefix] *'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><span>Please correct the errors and try again.</span>
            <ul><li style="display:none"></li></ul>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Include</legend>
            <input name="Include" type="text" required />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-js-val-prefix="Exclude">
            <legend>Exclude</legend>
            <input name="Exclude" type="text" required />
        </fieldset>
        <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not using the minified versions of the libraries as it may help when debugging.

I'd appreciate the help. Thanks

**Edit:**

If you change the script block to either of the following it works fine.

Without RequireJs:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script>
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: '[data-js-val-prefix] *'
    });
</script>
```

Without Unobtrusive JavaScript:

```
<script>
    require.config({
        paths: {
            'jquery': 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.3',
            'jquery.validate': 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate'
        },
        shim: {
            'jquery.validate': ['jquery']
        }
    });

    require(['jquery', 'jquery.validate'], function($) {
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            ignore: '[data-js-val-prefix] *'
        });

        $(function() {
            $('form').validate();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This suggests to me there's an issue with the unobtrusive validation library and RequireJs together. I'm sure I'm doing something trivial wrong.

Comment: Please include the code within your question.  Otherwise, after this is solved and your demo is gone, this is useless to future readers.

Comment: I'm going to modify the question once I remove the demo. I started writing it out but it became abit ugly and figured it may distract anyone who wishes to help.

Comment: So where is your `.validate()` code?  I really think it would be best for you to show the code for your concise example within the question.

Comment: I've modified the question with the code. I use the unobtrusive validation library (by Microsoft) which automatically wires up the validation for you. Please let me know if you need anything else. Thanks

Comment: Just a small follow up. I removed the unobtrusive validation stuff and wired it up manually and it worked so it seems there's something strange with the unobtrusive validation going on.

Comment: Sometimes I fail to see the advantage of MS's Unobtrusive Validation add-on.  Maybe in this case, just use jQuery Validation plugin without it.

Comment: It's part of a much larger application though and it's not possible to remove the unobtrusive validation at this stage.

Comment: All solved. Your comment above which I up-voted pointed me in the right direction and helped me learn a lot more about the unobtrusive validation library. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've answered my own question with the help of @Sparky. The issue happens because the jquery.validate.unobtrusive file wires up the validate method, if you then say $.validator.setDefaults in the callback function, it would have already wired up the validation and it will be ignored. If you change the require script block to the following:

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery.validate'], function($) {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: '[data-js-val-prefix] *'
    });

    require(['jquery.validate.unobtrusive']);
});
```

All is dandy. I hope this helps.